# What is the best method for comparing polynomials

Tags: statistics, polynomials

I have three polynomial curves. One curve is generated using experimental data and considered to be the true curve. The other two curves are generated using a Monte Carlo model of the system. I want to be able to compare the two curves against the true curve to determine which of the two curves best represents the true curve. Can you describe an approach that would best suit this situation. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a discrete data set. First you should define a norm for your error data. And then choose the data whose error norm is smaller.

1-norm, 2-norm, p-norm, $\infty-norm$ can be possible candidates.

If you have continuous data set, then try to measure the error data by integrating on the domain with a suitable integrand.

Answer (score 1):

Some statistical measure, like squared error over the relevant interval:
$$\int_a^b (p (x) - q (x))^2 \mathrm {d}  x $$